# Cache data storage

Tags: java, caching, gwt

Suppose I have a web page that I have built using Java and GWT for front end. Now I take some data from server and store it in a `HashMap` for faster access so that I don't have to go to server to get it again. Now where is this `HashMap` stored? In the browser?

Answer (score 0):

> Now I take some data from server and store it in a HashMap for faster access and so that I don't have to go to server to get ti again. Now where is this Hashmap stored? in the browser?

That depends entirely on how you write the code.  Most commonly though, you would store your HashMap on the server, either on a per-session basis or globally for all sessions, depending on whether the cached data is unique to a user.

Answer (score 0):

If the `HashMap` is in your client or shared package in the browser.

If the `HashMap` is in your server package, in the server (but in this case you must make an RPC call to the server everytime you need the `HashMap` contents).

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to go to server every time to get the data, you can store data on the client using **HTML5 Storage**.
[Please refer this link](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideHtml5Storage.html).